# What is wrong with this that would return the following error?

Tags: java

```
package data_structures;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ExpressionEvaluator implements Stack, Queue {
    private String userInput;
    public ExpressionEvaluator() {
        Userinput = null;
    }

    Iterator<E> st = new StringTokenizer();
    token = st.next();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

The problem has already occured at this point so I'm not continuing the code

The errors:

```
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: illegal start of typejava
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
^
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: <identifier> expected
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
^
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: ';' expected
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
^
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: illegal start of type
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
^
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: <identifier> expected
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
^
data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:10: ';' expected
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

Comment: [Don't leave unmatched parenthesis and braces in your code snippets!](http://xkcd.com/859/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should be inside a method. Not directly inside a class.

```
Iterator<E> st = new StringTokenizer();
    token = st.next();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

Comment: @RyanMatonis: If answer helped you don't forget to accept it by clicking on tick mark right beside answer.

Comment: `public boolean isOperator(String t) {
 return (t.equals("+") || t.equals("-") || t.equals("^") || t.equals("/") || t.equals("*"));
 }`

I have this inside a class compiling with this error:


data_structures/ExpressionEvaluator.java:40: illegal start of type
        for (int i = 0, i< 10, i++) {

Comment: @RyanMatonis: I would suggest post a new question with new code.

Answer (score 1):

This section

```
Iterator<E> st = new StringTokenizer();
token = st.next();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
```

Is not with a method or static initaliser.  All code must appear within a method inside a class

Answer (score 0):

Update you constructor as below because variable naming is not right:

```
  public ExpressionEvaluator() {
      userInput = null;
  }
```

Move the code below(UPDATED) the constructor code in **some method** as it can't exist standalone e.g.

```
public void evaluate(){
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(userInput);
   while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String token = st.nextToken();
      //manage your processing logic here
   }
}
```